# GUI automation using selenium in TCL

Tags: user-interface, selenium, automation, tcl

I want to use Selenium to automate a GUI for testing network devices in TCL. Can anybody help me to do that please. Have anyone seen or have experience using Selenium in combination with TCL?

Comment: Hi Karthik - what have you tried so far, and have you had any success?

Comment: Hi vincebowdren, I have done lot of  CLI automation using TCL EXPECT. and looking for a good tool to automate GUI .I need help to chose right path to do that.